# for in loop in not printing all the elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have the following code snippet :

```
var headers = { 'date' : 'Date', 
                'number' : 'Total Responses', 
                'number' : 'Total 404 not found',
                'number' : 'Total Connects', 
                'number' : 'Header Bytes', 
                'number' : 'Total Bytes',
                'number' : 'Total Connects', 
                'number' : 'Data Read',
                'number' : 'Files Requested'
            };
for (var index in headers) {
    console.log(index + " : " + headers[index])
}
```

And that's not printing the entire map:

```
date : Date
number : Files Requested
```

why? Everything seems fine for me (obviously is not) but I can't figure out why I'm not being able to print the entire structure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unique property names.

```
var headers = { 'date' : 'Date', 
            'number1' : 'Total Responses', 
            'number2' : 'Total 404 not found',
            'number3' : 'Total Connects', 
            'number4' : 'Header Bytes', 
            'number5' : 'Total Bytes',
            'number6' : 'Total Connects', 
            'number7' : 'Data Read',
            'number8' : 'Files Requested'
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a property with the same name.  So the equivalent would be:

```
var headers = {};
headers.date = 'Date';
headers.number = 'Total Responses';
//etc
headers.number = 'Files Requested';
```

You are overwriting the property so the last one wins.

I always think of a JavaScript object as a dictionary of key/value pairs.  In the same way, you can only have one key, in this case, `number`.

Answer (score 2):

Objects can only have one value for each key. If you have two or more of the same key, the last key is used.

Answer (score 1):

Your object only contains two fields.  When an object is initialised, if two fields have the same name, the value for that name is overwritten with the last one.  So the output is correct for a JavaScript program even if it may not be what you want.  Perhaps you could use an array of objects, e.g. `[{'date': 'Date'}, {'number': 'Total Responses'}, {'number': 'Total 404 not found'}, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop instead of a for. It appears that you are declaring an index variable but you should set it to zero and increment so the loop can iterate through the array as an alternative.